# How to tell CreateProcess I do not require user rights elevation

Tags: winapi, windows-7, uac, elevated-privileges

I am trying to run an executable file which contains "update" in file name, for example "`mycoolupdate`", without extension.

If it were a normal "`mycoolupdate.exe`" file, Windows Explorer in Windows 7 would automatically decide based on the file name that it requires user rights elevation.

I thought it is only a shell behaviour and does not affect "`CreateProcess`" WinAPI function, especially when the file name does not contain `.exe` extension, but it does not seem to be true. It turns out that the same rules apply to WinAPI.

So `GetLastError` returns

> The requested operation requires elevation

Is there a way to tell `CreateProcess` that I do not require user rights elevation despite the suspicious file name?

Comment: Add an application manifest to the executable, as described in the documentation for UAC

Comment: Ok. Manifest. Thank you. But may be something for the CreateProcess side?

Comment: Don't think so. UAC is nearly 15 years old, you really shouldn't be building executables without manifests these days.

Comment: Adding a manifest is best, but when that is not possible, there are other options available. Such as setting the new process's `__compat_layer` environment variable to `RunAsInvoker`, for instance. There are several questions on SO on how to use `__compat_layer`

Comment: May be with `CreateProcessAsUser()`.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: Thank you. It might be an alternative, but there are two potential issues: 1. We schould know password; 2. Elevation request might be triggered again (should test this).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Windows Vista a correctly written application is required to have an application manifest.

As a developer you are required to supply this.

In this case, your manifest indicates that your application was correctly written for Windows Vista (or newer). Otherwise Windows assumes that your application is not correctly written for Windows Vista.